# Google Sheets - comparing dates and returning the latest row with requirements

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that uses a query to pull data from another sheet. This data, looks a bit like this.

```
DATE       STOREID OTHERDATA
02/11/2017 Store 1 Other data 1
01/11/2017 Store 1 Other data 2
09/10/2017  Store 2 Other data 3
05/10/2017  Store 2 Other data 4
```

I'm looking for a way for it to return only the latest date row per store, as seen below.

```
DATE       STOREID OTHERDATA
02/11/2017 Store 1 Other data 1
09/10/2017  Store 2 Other data 3
```

The query I'm currently using looks something like this:

```
=query(DATASHEET!A2:CF11, "select C, CC, L,CD, E, BZ, CA, CB where (BF='CUSTOMERNAME1') order by C desc, CC, L, BZ desc",0)
```

Is this possible to make the query look at all dates and storeIDs and only return the highest date per storeID? I can imagine doing this in another language with a loop/for, but my Google results tell me it's not possible with query.

If that is the case, how would you recommend I do this in the data sheet so I could have a column say either LATEST / NOT LATEST for each row and then use query with a WHERE statement?

Here's an example sheet I tried setting up in case it helps explain what I'm trying to do.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/removed

Any help is appreciated as I've spent all day trying to figure it out. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY({ROW(A2:A),SORT(A2:C)}, "SELECT MAX(Col1) WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col3 LABEL MAX(Col1)''",0),{ROW(A2:A), SORT(A2:C)},{2,3,4},0))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Much appreciated. 

How would I go about adding other requirements and columns? 

My original query: select C, CC, L,CD, E, BZ, CA, CB where (BF='CUSTOMERNAME1') order by C desc, CC, L, BZ desc 

I tried adding another column but got an aggregate error. Any advice?

Comment: Adding more columns to my query, all you'd need to do is expand all the ranges; `{ROW(A2:A), SORT(A2:**<BIGGER RANGE HERE>**)}` then also adding the new columns to the VLOOKUP return; `{2,3,4,**<MORE COLUMNS HERE>**}`. The _Query_ chunk of the formula is only picking out the max rows of the dates. The Vlookup is matching the rest of the cells based on the query results. If you wanted more from that data set, I'd suggest keeping that data on one sheet, then re-query it from another sheet.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for explaining, got the extra columns I wanted in there without any issues.. 

Last question, I want to use order by on two columns, however, wherever I add the order by in the query, it seems to break it. Is it possible to have it order by? (ex. ORDER BY Col3, Col 5)

Currently it looks like this: =ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY({ROW(DATA!C2:C),SORT(DATA!C2:CF)}, "SELECT MAX(Col1) WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL AND (Col57='CUST 1') GROUP BY Col3 LABEL MAX(Col1)''",0),{ROW(DATA!A2:C), SORT(DATA!C2:CF)},{2,80,11,81,4,77,78,79},0))

Comment: Sorry, I understand now what you mean. I just referred to the data in a new sheet with a new query and was therefore able to easily sort it correctly without trying to modify the existing code that works. Many thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(B1:B11),SORT({B1:C11,A1:A11},3,0),{3,1,2},0))
```

By Reverse `SORT`ing by Column A, and `VLOOKUP`ing `UNIQUE` values, We have the latest row.