# Compare and Return Date Based on Criteria From Multiple Cells

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm looking to compare dates in a Google Sheet and then return the last/latest date where multiple criteria matches.

Here is specifically what I'm trying to do...

...Find the last/latest release date from Column C (blue column), where Columns F, H, J and L (orange columns) ALL match the same column cells from all the other rows. Then return that last/latest date and fill it into Column D.

In this demo sheet here...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WgI8lr3y-68n7jzbcinG-s-YAmRXFrTg-K8SlDG98jM/

Between that description and the demo sheet, I hope that makes sense.

I did find another similar request (but couldn't make sense of how to adapt it to my own needs) here...
[Google Sheets - comparing dates and returning the latest row with requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071458/google-sheets-comparing-dates-and-returning-the-latest-row-with-requirements)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I missed up the "Expected Results" column but fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,map(F:F,H:H,J:J,L:L,lambda(f,h,j,l,join(,{f,h,j,l}))),
     map(C3:C,F3:F,H3:H,J3:J,L3:L,lambda(c,f,h,j,l,if(c="",,chooserows(filter(C:C,Σ=join(,{f,h,j,l})),-1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is great. Is there a way to adapt this into an array formula to use it in the header row above?

Comment: Use it as `=vstack("Header", <formula>)`

Comment: I couldn't sleep so I played with it some more. Unfortunately, as soon as I sort by another column, (by Movie Title, Column A, for example) it breaks. (See the sheet tab with your name.) Whereas, if I sort first by Release Date and then Transaction ID, the Last Release Dates show as expected.

Comment: do you need the **last date** available in the list(row wise) OR the **latest date** from within the list?! What is the ideal expected output for data in rows 19,20,21 of the screenshot in my answer (BB451-5615615 Transaction ID)

Comment: I need it to be the latest release date (the newest release) as opposed to the last release date listed in the column or lowest in the column. Sorry if I wasn't clear. Thanks again.

Comment: So its not `06/06/1986` (as you quoted in your expected output) and its supposed to be `05/04/2021`?!

Comment: I had screwed up some of my entries on the expected results .I had fixed it last night but it was probably after your original efforts. I'm really sorry for that as I'm sure it completely confused what I was trying to communicate.

Comment: Test the updated formula added to the sheet. replaced this part of the formula `chooserows(filter(C:C,Σ=join(,{f,h,j,l})),-1)` with `+sort(filter(C:C,Σ=join(,{f,h,j,l})),1,)`

Comment: I just triple checked the demo sheet and then re-duplicated the base sheet for a new test page with your newest work (I might have fixed the expected results on the base sheet but not the test sheet, ugh) and it all seems to work perfectly now. Thank you so much. And again, I apologize for the poor communication and errors on the sheet.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and thank you for everything... I just discovered a minor flaw with my original request. In a few rare cases, when N/A is entered as the Transaction ID, it's usually because there is a 3rd party Transaction ID (from PayPal, etc) and it messes things up in some cases. Is it possible to add a IF (H="N/A")or(H="?"), THEN add another column (ColN) into the mix for consideration? See the test sheet with your work for hopefully a better idea. Thanks again!

Comment: Updated the formula to include the condition

Comment: That did it. Thank you again for everything!!

Answer (score 1):

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

You can create a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) in Google Sheets specifically designed for your use case, with the help of [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/). To access the Apps Script editor, from your spreadsheet, go to **Extensions > Apps Script**.

Some key notes regarding this method:

1. You can use this function or formula as you normally do on Google Sheets, but it will perform the set of processes defined in your use case ("compare dates in a Google Sheet and then return the last/latest date where multiple criteria matches").
2. On the script, you are required to input 5 ranges: the reference column (where the dates are to be taken), and the 4 columns that needs to be checked if there are match/es. For your reference, this is how the custom formula would look like:

```
=returnDateFromCriteria(ran_ref, ran1, ran2, ran3, ran4)
```

Note that you can rename this function in the Apps Script editor, to whichever function name you prefer. However, **renaming any of the parameters in the function may require you to adjust values in the script itself**, for it to function the same.

As for the script itself, **you can refer to the sample script below for your reference:**

```
 /**
 * A custom formula function that returns the last entered date on
 * a specific column, based on if a match is found from multiple criteria
 * across other columns
 * @param {ran_ref} Reference column range from where the dates will be extracted
 * @param {ran1, ran2, ...} The column range/s where the criteria are to be checked for a match
 * @return A resulting list of dates which have already been sorted and matched
 * @customfunction
*/
function returnDateFromCriteria(ran_ref, ran1, ran2, ran3, ran4) {
  // filters all blank values, and reduces the retrieved values into their respective 1D arrays
  // note: this is needed for the matching later in the script
  var match1 = ran1.filter(x => x != "").flat();
  var match2 = ran2.filter(x => x != "").flat();
  var match3 = ran3.filter(x => x != "").flat();
  var match4 = ran4.filter(x => x != "").flat();
  var ref = ran_ref.filter(x => x != "").flat();
  var res = [];
  var ctr = 0;

  // this is to re-arrange the date format from the spreadsheet into the month/day/year format
  // since Google Apps Script retrieves both the date and time as its value by default
  for (i = 0; i < match3.length; i++) {
    match3[i] = Utilities.formatDate(match3[i], 'America/New_York', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    ref[i] = Utilities.formatDate(ref[i], 'America/New_York', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
  }
  // the full script to update the dates for matching rows
  for (i = 0; i < ref.length; i++) {
    // if two rows have identical values across the defined column ranges
    if ((match1[i] == match1[i + 1]) && (match2[i] == match2[i + 1]) && (match3[i] == match3[i + 1]) && (match4[i] == match4[i + 1])) {
      // this if statement checks if an active match exists
      // if so, it updates the date already pushed in the resulting array
      // with the last value retrieved
      if (ctr) {
        res[i - 1] = ref[i + 1];
      }
      // if a match is just detected, the last value is pushed onto the resulting array
      res.push(ref[i + 1]);
      ctr++;
    }
    // terminates the existing match, to be able to check for other matches
    else if (ctr) {
      res.push(ref[i]);
      ctr = 0;
    }
    // if a row is unique amongst other values
    else {
      res.push(ref[i]);
    }
  }

  // this returns the resulting array back to the spreadsheet
  // reformatted into a 2D array (as a spreadsheet cell is 2D, with a defined row and column)
  return res.map(x => [x]);
}
```

Once you have saved this script, you can proceed to use the formula normally on Google Sheets.

### OUTPUT

[image]

### REFERENCES

You can refer to the following links on the functions used in the custom function script:

- [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [flat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_array_flat.asp)
- [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates)

Comment: Thank you. I'm heading to bed but I'll look at it better tomorrow. The first thing I noticed though, is that it is used in the first date row. Is it possible to adapt it so that it can be used in the array formula header row above it?.

Comment: Ah, I see; yes, we could tweak the custom formula so that the row above the 1st set of data is included in the list. Although just to clarify: a) the formula will be entered on row 2, and it should list the sorted dates on the rows below, and b) as you mentioned on a comment above, you actually want to list the **latest** date (as in, the most recent date chronologically) and not the **last** date listed on your sheet?

Comment: Yes. It should be returning the most recent release date. I could have worded things better and the fact that I had a few incorrect entries on the expected results. Colin, probably didn't help. Sorry about that.